# getWidth not updating

Tags: java, android

Why is it that both outs are printing 84? The first one should read 84, the second should read 220. If I click a second time, both outs read 220.

```
public void btnClick(View v) {
    System.out.println(textView1.getWidth());
    textView1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 55);
    System.out.println(textView1.getWidth());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing text size will not change the size of the view if it has already been measured.  SetTextSize() will trigger an invalidate(), but that only triggers an onDraw() in the future.  The view will not be measured again, and its width and height will remain the same.  You can call requestLayout() on the view to get the width and height recalculated.

If you just want to see the size of the text after changing the size (in terms of its dimensions) you can try [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextBounds(char[], int, int, android.graphics.Rect)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextBounds%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect%29)

Comment: I'm trying to get the max text size that will still allow the textview to fit in a certain area. I need that value to set the max on a seekbar. I was thinking of doing a while loop. While textview.getWidth() < layout.getWidth() { setTextSize +1px at a time }

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to do that than requestLayout maybe 100 times in a loop?

Comment: I think a better approach would be to start with the dimensions of that "certain area", whether it is a container view or space between other views. Find out the max width and height you have available, then start with your min text size value and use a new Paint object.  You can use Paint.setTextSize (float textSize) and then Paint.getTextBounds (String text, int start, int end, Rect bounds) to get what the bounds would be with your text size.  Keep increasing or decreasing your text size until the Rect bounds fits inside your max width and height.

Answer (score 1):

The `TextView` size isn't immediately updated after a call to `setTextSize()`. It just invalidates the view and will be updated later. Computing the size of a View is expensive because it depends on the entire layout, so it's not done immediately.

Try to get the width a bit later and you will get the right value.

Comment: Checking back later will not help unless onMeasure() has subsequently been called.  Otherwise the view's width and height will remain the same.  Also, if the view's layout_width and layout_height is set to a fixed value, and not wrap_content, changing text size won't change the size of the view.

Comment: You're right, but I supposed he set it to "wrap_content" and he just wondered why he didn't get the new width immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second getWidth() is being run before the setTextSize is completed.  Therefore getting the same result.  Java doesn't wait for each line of code to be completed before running the next line.

If the setTextSize line takes 5ms to complete and the next line is run 2ms after the setTextLine is run then the result would be the same.  You might divide these into separate methods. Or add a wait.

Is this code just for debugging?